# How to populate empty list with AM / PM values based on "datetime64" variable from a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, date, data-science, feature-engineering

I am new to ML and Data Science and learning as much as I can by myself now while looking for positions in Data Science / Business Analytics.

I am working on my personal project to build ML algorithms to predict if a customer will show up to their existing appointment.

I am facing a problem working with a column of 'datetime64' format. This column is called 'ScheduledDay', and can be seen in the image below.
[image]

My ultimate goal is to create a new column that will contain 'AM' or 'PM' values based on whether a time in a 'ScheduledDay' column is AM time (< 12:00pm) or PM (<= 12:00pm).

I started to work on this by creating an empty dictionary to hold "AM" and "PM" values. Then I am trying to run a for loop to populate my empty dictionary with AM or PM values, as shown in the code below.

```
# Create dictionary to hold results
appointment_counts = {'AM': 0, 'PM': 0}

# Loop over all trips
for hour in my_df['ScheduledDay']:

    if hour['ScheduledDay'].hour < 12:
        appointment_counts['AM'] += 1

    else:
        appointment_counts['PM'] += 1

print(appointment_counts)
```

This gave me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable
```

To solve this, I created a new column - 'ScheduledDaySTR' - to have same values as 'ScheduledDay', but as of type 'object' to experiment:

```
my_df['ScheduledDaySTR'] = my_df['ScheduledDay'].astype(str)
```

Then, I tried my for loop and empty list again:

```
# Create dictionary to hold results
appointment_counts = {'AM': 0, 'PM': 0}

# Loop over all trips
for hour in my_df['ScheduledDaySTR']:
    if hour['ScheduledDaySTR'].hour < 12:
        appointment_counts['AM'] += 1

    else:
        appointment_counts['PM'] += 1

print(appointment_counts)
```

This threw me a new error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I tried solving this error by creating a new column with same values as 'ScheduledDay', but of type 'int':

```
my_df['ScheduledDayINT'] = my_df['ScheduledDay'].astype(int)
```

Then, I tried my for loop again:

```
# Create dictionary to hold results
appointment_counts = {'AM': 0, 'PM': 0}

# Loop over all trips
for hour in my_df['ScheduledDayINT']:
    if hour['ScheduledDayINT'].hour < 12:
        appointment_counts['AM'] += 1

    else:
        appointment_counts['PM'] += 1

print(appointment_counts)
```

And, I am getting another error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I am stuck at how I can approach this problem. I am new to data science and trying to learn by myself.

Comment: The issue is that you are iterating over each value in the Series, `my_df['ScheduledDay']` but you are trying to access the data as if you were iterating over each row in the `mf_df` dataframe. Try `hour.hour` in your loop. Or change your iteration to `for row in my_df:` and then use `row['ScheduledDay'].hour`

Comment: @chris thank you for you input. When I tried 'hour.hour' on each of 3 for loops, it gives me the same errors as outlined above. When I tried your second solution, all 3 versions thew the same error: 'TypeError: string indices must be integers' , even when I tried doing in on a variable with dates of type 'int64'

Comment: on what line are you getting the error? Just focus on the first loop, the other 2 are not needed. And try adding a `print(hour)` and `print(type(hour))` to your loop to see what it looks like on each iteration. Or edit your question to include a sample dataframe so people can help you better.

Comment: @chris never mind, I finally solved it! I was trying to implement your first advice in a wrong manner, which is why I couldn't get the necessary result. But, now it worked. Thank you for you help!